# how to terminate a windows service if the thread inside it terminates for an handled exception?

Tags: delphi

I'm using delphi Athens and I have a service application.
Inside there, I create a subthread like this:

```
procedure TMainSvc.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
  FMainThread := TMainThread.Create(True);
  FMainThread.FreeOnTerminate := true;
  FMainThread.OnTerminate := MainThread_Terminate;
  FMainThread.Start;
  Started := True;
end;

procedure TMainSvc.MainThread_Terminate(Sender: TObject);
begin  
  //
end;

procedure TMainSvc.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  while not Terminated do
    begin
      ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(false);
      TThread.Sleep(1000);
    end;
end;
```

The main thread contains something like this:

```
procedure TMainThread.Execute;
begin
  try
    while not Terminated do
      begin
        // some code
        TThread.Sleep(200);
      end;
  except
    on e: exception do
      begin  
        // error handling
      end;
  end;
end;
```

So, what's happening is that for some reason inside while cycle I receive an error, so I handle the error and the program will complete the execute function.
What I would like to do, is that the service will stop itself in this situation.
Instead, the service will stay active doing nothing inside ServiceExecute.

So I tried setting OnTerminate like this:

```
procedure TMainSvc.MainThread_Terminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MainSvc.DoStop;
end;
```

and I have set the serviceStop like this:

```
procedure TMainSvc.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  // FMainThread.Terminate;
  FMainThread.WaitFor;
  Stopped := True;
end;
```

However the program just stays forever waiting the "WaitFor" procedure.

So my final questions are:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What should I do to achieve what I need? (in case of errors in the cycle, terminate the service)
3. Why even if FMainThread terminated (it entered onterminate) if I check inside ServiceStop: FMainThread.Finished, FMainThread.CheckTerminated it seems they are not terminated?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are waiting on your worker thread inside of its own `OnTerminate` event handler. That is a *guaranteed deadlock*, since `TThread.WaitFor()` will not exit until the thread is fully terminated, but the thread will not fully terminate until the event handler has exited.

Instead, you need to signal the [`TService.ServiceThread`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.SvcMgr.TService.ServiceThread) to terminate itself, eg:

```pascal
procedure TMainSvc.MainThread_Terminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ServiceThread.Terminate;
end;
```

The alternative is to manually simulate an SCM `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` request by directly calling the service's `ServiceController`, eg:

```pascal
procedure TMainSvc.MainThread_Terminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Controller(SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP);
end;
```

---

Also, you can (and should) get rid of your `TService.OnExecute` event handler, as you don't actually need it at all. You are not doing anything in it that `TService` itself wouldn't already do internally when `OnExecute` is not assigned. So let it handle SCM requests automatically for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I removed OnExecute (I thought it was essential) and I wrote MainThread_Terminate as you suggested. However, with ServiceThread.Terminate I can manually stop the service successfully, but the service does not terminate itself automatically, even if it passes through that after the error in MainThread. Any idea?

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you again, I changed the code as you proposed but it was not working. Then I used both your solutions and it's working. Is it correct? So, if inside MainThread_Terminate I do: ServiceThread.Terminate; Controller(SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP); it stops correctly